# PHP Composer cannot find any classes

Tags: php, permissions, file-permissions, composer-php, windows-server-2012

We have a server running Windows Server 2012 on AWS. We use composer to manage packages, and run the `composer [install/update]` commands on the main Administrator account. We run our scripts as a `web` user.

Everything was working find, but a new script that I am working on, cannot find any classes. It turns out that the composer package folders, only have permissions set for Admin users, the web user does not have permissions to read the folders.

This has never been a problem before, should composer be applying permissions like this? Is there a way to configure composer to allow our `web` user to have R/W permissions on the packages?

It just seems like a hack / workaround to have to set the permissions manually each time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is still interested, the issue was fixed here https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1714#issuecomment-19693312, running `composer self-update` will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

With permission management you have generally two options, either you run the command as the right user (web) so the files are owned by it and you have no problems, or you have to fix the file perms after if by default they are not readable. I don't really see a way around this.

Comment: Yeah running the command as `webuser` seems like the best option. I just don't understand how this has been working before, but something has suddenly changed to stop it.

Comment: One thing is that we now always unzip packages in the temp dir. This has to change though because it caused permission issuse in various places, but in the meantime you could try to set the TEMP env var to something the web user owns while running composer. Might fix it.

Comment: Oh that sounds like a good solution if it works, hadn't thought of that. Thanks

Comment: I've taken a look at our dev folder, `composer update` hasn't been executed in a few weeks, however, we have read permissions for **all** users on all files in the `vendor` directory. What has changed in composer and why?